# PHP Best practice to display all lines from file containing enormus number of lines

Tags: php, mysql, string, file

I have one file 1.2MB and in it, there are 36k+ lines of text and probably growing. The problem is that I want to display all the lines from input.txt but since there are too many lines I get out with a browser crash...What I have tried so far is:

```
<?php
    $handle = fopen("input.txt", "r");
      if ($handle) {
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        echo '<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">'.$line.'</li>';
        }
    fclose($handle);
    } else {
         echo 'error';
      }
?>
```

This code works for files that are about 40KB approx 1400lines anything more will result in a crash...

After that I thought if I load that file to db and then conn with php and get data from base I will be able to display all lines, but again I was wrong

```
            <?php
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } 
            $sql = "SELECT ime_pjesme FROM pjesme";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo '<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">'. $row["ime_pjesme"].'</li>';
                }
            } else {
                echo "0 results";
            }
            $conn->close();
            ?>
```

So my question is is there any way/method I could use to get those lines displayed in browser or is there way to load it and then display 50 by 50 etc?

Comment: Use datatable with ajax request.
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax

Comment: _"but again I was wrong"_ - and how exactly does that surprise you now, considering that you still sent the exact same thing to the browser, only assembled on the server side in a different way? _"or is there way to load it and then display 50 by 50 etc?"_ - go research/ read up on _pagination_.

Comment: Define 'crash'... Did you browser run out of memory? Did the script timeout or run out of memory? For something that will actually scale, Google "pagination".

Comment: Showing 36k lines in the browser in one go doesn't really make sense and will most likely always make the browser slow, or even hang. Do as others have suggested, use pagination.

Comment: tnx all for response I figure it out with pagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to display the file a page at a time.

There are many libraries that will do it nicely for you, but to understand the mechanisms, here's how to do it with just the jQuery library and some PHP.

Simply put, you need two files. The first will display the page counter/selector and the area where the rows will appear. Say that you want 50 rows at a time:

```
$pages = floor(($rownumber + 50 - 1)/ 50);
print "<ul class=\"pageselect\">";
for ($i = 0; $i < $pages; $i++) {
    $p = $i + 1;
    print "<li data-page=\"{$p}\">Page {$p}</li>";
}
print "</ul>";
```

You organize the CSS so that the LI elements are all nice, centered and horizontal. Then you use e.g. jQuery to attach an event handler to the clicking on one of those LI's by delegating to the parent UL, in Javascript:

```
$('ul.pageselect').on('click', 'li', function() {
    var wanted = $(this).attr('data-page');
    $.post('/path/to/page_load.php', { page: wanted })
     .then(reply => {
           // "reply" is the object returned by the loader PHP.
           $('#lines').empty();
           for (var l = 0; l < reply.lines.length; l++) {
               $('#lines').append($('<p>').text(reply.lines[l]));
           }
     });
});
```

The delegate function issues an AJAX POST call to the second PHP file, and expect a JSON reply (called `reply` here) to be processed.

The above will kill the contents of a DIV such as `<div id="lines"></div>` and fill it with as many P's as there are lines in the loader reply.

The loader receives a parameter which is the page number, translates it to an absolute line number, runs the select and returns everything in JSON format:

```
$from = (((int)$_POST['page'])-1) * 50;
if ($from < 0) { $from = 0; }
// Run a SELECT with OFFSET {$from},50 to fetch at most 50 rows

$reply = [
    'total' => $total, // use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS to get the total number
    'lines' => [ ]
];
while ($rs->fetch(PDO::PDO_FETCH_ASSOC) as $line) {
    $reply['lines'] = "This line is {$line['text']}.";
}

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF8');
// Return JSON encoding of $reply to the caller.
exit(json_encode($reply));
```

You will find the browser tools invaluable to inspect what's going on with the AJAX calls. The "loader" file you will be able to recycle later with most of the niftier libraries.

Comment: I'd like to emphasis getting a library to do this kind of thing is probably the best option as it looks like you will likely run into memory problems soon... especially as you are asking for "best practice". :)

Comment: @Edward - Why would this example give you memory problems? It suggests that the OP put all the lines into a database and then fetch 50 lines per page. It's just a standard pagination.

Comment: this won't, you are paging your results, my comment was directed at op